# How to get smooth scrolling using AVPlayer within UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am embedding an `AVPlayer` in a `UICollectionViewCell` however, the scrolling of my `UICollectionView` is always really jerky because of this.

I cache the `AVAsset` after the video has loaded and use that when the same cell reappears, but it's still fairly jerky, especially when it first loads the video. There doesn't seem to be any tips/tutorials on this online, but Instagram/Twitter/Facebook/Vine all managed to achieve it.

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this?

**My Code**

For loading the video:

```
func loadVideo(from urlString: String, forCell cell: VideoCell) {
    if let video = model.videoCache[urlString] {
        cell.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: video))
    } else if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        cell.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        model.videoCache[urlString] = cell.player?.currentItem?.asset
    }
    cell.playerView.player = cell.player
    cell.player?.isMuted = isVideoMuted
    cell.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
}
```

PlayerView:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

/// A simple UIView subclass that is backed by an AVPlayerLayer layer.
class PlayerView: UIView {
    var player: AVPlayer? {
        get {
            return playerLayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerLayer.player = newValue
        }
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
    }

    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }
}
```

VideoCell:

```
class VideoCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var playerView: PlayerView!
    var player: AVPlayer?
}
```

I'm using [IGListKit](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit) to control my `UICollectionView`, so each of my cells is controlled by a section controller. The part where it loads the cell for the `UICollectionViewCell` is:

```
override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCell(withNibName: "VideoCell", bundle: nil, for: self, at: index) as? VideoCell,
        let video = object
        else { fatalError("Could not dequeue video cell") }

    let videoLocation = video.loc
    loadVideo(from: videoLocation, forCell: cell)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you add you code which you have tried?

Comment: You shouldn't load video asset directly because loading such huge data result lags in scrolling, instead use image thumbnail to show video and when user click on it, then load your video asset.

Comment: @Venkadesh I've added my current code

Comment: @Ajaysaini I don't want it like that, I want it to autoplay like it does on social media apps

Comment: Can you post the code which you wrote on `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` ?

Comment: @Venkadesh Ok, I added the relevant part. I am using `IGListKit` to control my `UICollectionView` though. This shouldn't make a difference to how the cell appears though, just a different way of controlling the cells. The concept is still the same.